# How to add a testcase to ltp

Tags: c, linux, shell, kernel

I need add a simple testcase which is writen by `shell` to [ltp](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/). I add a makefile follow this [page](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/documentation/how-to/ltp.php#_6). 
It said that I should create a makefile like this:

```
all:
install:
    @ln -f mail_tests.sh ../../bin/mail_tests.sh

clean:
```

but I don't know `../../bin/mail_tests.sh` in where. I mean that I can't find a bin dir in ltp's source dir.
So, how can I add my test case.

Comment: Have you tried running the test suite? Does it look for `bin/mail_tests.sh`? If it does, just create the `bin` directory and set up the link.

Comment: thank you, I have tried to do that. and pass the make && make install.  then I run ltp, but it said can't find that file.  so, I don't think it's that dir.    :) sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

The LTP sf.net pages are obsolete.

There is some developer documentation in LTP GitHub wiki which should be hopefully detailed enough for people who wants to write a LTP testcase without any prior knowledge, see:

https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/wiki/Test-Writing-Guidelines

https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/wiki/BuildSystem

If anything is not clear feel free to ask on the project mailing list at ltp-list@lists.sourceforge.net.